# Releasing a python package with tkinter for pip

Tags: python, tkinter, packaging, pypi

I have build a small quiz using Tkinter in Python and I wish to release the game for all to play, so that people can just `pip install` and play the game.

I have gone through the docs to release a PyPi package, I released one, it gets successfully installed. However, I'm unable to launch the application from commandline nor can I look for the binary. I don't know where am I going wrong. Please help me out here.

My setup.py file looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup
from codecs import open
from os import path

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst')) as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='py-quiz',
    version='0.1.1',
    description='Python based Quiz game.',
    long_description=long_description,
    author='Abhijit Nathwani',
    author_email='abhijit.nathwani@gmail.com',
    LICENSE='MIT',
    url='https://github.com/abhijitnathwani/PyQuiz',
    keywords='pyquiz tkinter'

)
```

To package it, I use

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

The package is successfully added to PyPi package and I could install it using:

```
pip install py-quiz
```

The output of the installation:

```
Collecting py-quiz
  Downloading py-quiz-0.1.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: py-quiz
  Running setup.py install for py-quiz ... done
Successfully installed py-quiz-0.1.1
```

But then when i do,

```
user@somecomputer:~/PyQuiz$ py-quiz
py-quiz: command not found
```

How do I launch the game from command line? Please help me out here.

The application code is maintained [here](https://github.com/abhijitnathwani/PyQuiz/).

Comment: Abhijit, u have missed to register setup file before create source distribution $ python setup.py register, for details https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html

Comment: I did that. But got the response ` Server response (410): Project pre-registration is no longer required or supported, so continue directly to uploading files.`. Registering has now been deprecated. We just have to upload directly. @Anup

Comment: Add entry points in setup: 
entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'my_project = my_project.__main__:main'
          ]
      },

Comment: I tried as per your direction, but still doesn''t help me. Renamed my final script to "<underscore><underscore>main<underscore><underscore>.py" and added a main() function to be called. Still no good. Can you please elaborate more ? @Anup

Comment: I see you solved the problem [here](https://github.com/abhijitnathwani/PyQuiz/commit/7ba5333478877693a6637a30d7461338d9aeb60c) (alright!). It'd be kind to future searchers to add your answer below. ;-)

Comment: @mattwilkie Thank you for pointing out. Added the answer :)

Comment: Great! ... We can delete these last few comments now; they won't be interesting to the future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem above by making the following changes.
There must be a package created in the directory and the folder structure should be as follows:

```
<Directory>
|-setup.py
|-dist
|-LICENCSE
|-readme
|-<package-name>
 |-__init__.py
 |-__main__.py
 |-other files
```

and in the `setup.py` the following change should be

`entry_points={
        'console_scripts':['<command_name> = <package_name>.__main__:<function to be called>']`

In my case, it is as follows:

`entry_points={
        'console_scripts':['py-quiz = py_quiz.__main__:main']`

The main point is to create a package inside your project directory. This should solve major problems.